# Admob still making requests when app closed or in background?

Tags: java, android, sdk, admob

If my app is running and I press either the home or back buttons my app will still continue to make ad requests as if it is running. I can see this in logcat.

```
02-21 11:52:38.118: INFO/AdMobSDK(5782): No fill.  Server replied that no ads are available (9041ms)
02-21 11:52:51.391: INFO/CheckinService(5182): Preparing to send checkin request
02-21 11:52:51.391: INFO/EventLogService(5182): Accumulating logs since 1298260031221
02-21 11:52:51.461: INFO/CheckinTask(5182): Sending checkin request (3032 bytes)
02-21 11:53:47.164: INFO/AdMobSDK(5782): No fill.  Server replied that no ads are available (9044ms)
```

The above is all after I have closed my application using the home button. It does the same thing if I use the back button though. Why on earth is it doing this? It even does it if i set the ad view to null in 'onPause()'. How can I stop it from happening?

Comment: If I remove the line of code that says: ad.setRequestInterval(60); it seems to work fine... I am assuming it is a bug with the AdMobSDK?

Answer (score 0):

Haven't used AdMob SDK, so not sure if the setRequestInterval is the only solution. By default, the apps in android are not killed when you press back button or home button. Android platform takes care of closing the app if there is no more memory available for running other apps. You can try checking if the app is in foreground and then make the call to admob sdk.